# Given $P(A \mid B)$ and $P(A \mid C)$, what is $P(A \mid B,C)$?

Tags: probability

So I am trying to calculate the probability of an event $A$ based on indicator variables $B$ and $C$. I have calculated $P(A \mid B)$ and $P(A \mid C)$, which is to say, given either of these happening, I can infer a reasonable value for $P(A)$. I would like to be able to take into account when multiple indicators are true, and give extra weight to these over cases where just one is true. Assuming $B$ and $C$ are independent, is there a straightforward way to calculate $P(A \mid B, C)$ from the individual conditional probabilities? If necessary, I can try to create some additional statistics with other probabilities as well.

Comment: If $A$ stands for "being a millionaire", while $B,C$ stand for winning two specific lotteries, then $P(A|B)=P(A|C)>.99$, while $P(A)$ is low.  I don't know what $P(A|B,C)$ means, but if it's $P(A|B\cap C)$, then that could be anything -- if $B\cap C$ is a single individual.

Comment: are the probabilities summed greater than 100% ? If so you could simply look at the minimum possible overlap, to find a lower bound of the double indicator scenario. though this approach wouldn't be exact of course.

Comment: okay I'll admit it may not even be the correct approach so an example of what I mean is in order. if 50% of coins are counterfeit, and 60% of coins are used you can guarantee that 10% of coins are both counterfeit and used. Otherwise you've double counted things potentially ( or over-counted).

Comment: okay sorry I'm somewhat wrong because I did the reversed question in my head.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8xlOm2wPAA  may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in general with only that knowledge.

What we can know about $P(A|BC)$ is:

- if either of these given probabilities are $0$ we know that $P(A|BC)=0$.
- if either of these given probabilities are $1$ we know that $P(A|BC)=1$
- otherwise $P(A|BC)$ can be anything in $[0,1]$

We can see the last case by assigning the probabilities for varius events. We see that by assigning $P(ABC) = \theta P(BC)$ and $P(A^CBC) = (1-\theta P(BC))$ we will have $P(A|BC) = P(ABC)/P(BC) = \theta$. Also we have that

$$P(A|B) 
= {P(AB)\over P(B)} 
= {P(ABC) + P(ABC^C)\over P(BC) + P(ABC^C) + P(A^CBC^C) }
= {\theta P(BC) + P(ABC^C)\over P(BC) + P(ABC^C) + P(A^CBC^C) }
$$

We see that by setting $P(BC)$ small enough we can by select $P(ABC^C)$ and $P(A^CBC^C)$ so that $P(A|B)$ becomes anything less than $1$, and we can do this so that $P(BC)$ and $P(B^CC)$ both are less than $1/3$. We can do similar thing for $P(A|C)$.

This makes that $P(B\cup C)<1$ and finally we assign $P(A^CB^CC^C) = P(B^CC^C)$.

By this construct we can with arbitrary $\theta < 1$ and $P(A|B), P(A|C)\notin\{0,1\}$ we can have $P(A|BC) = \theta$.

For constructing $P(A|BC)=1$ we instead set 
$$P(ABC) = 1/(1+P(A|B)+P(A|C)$$
$$P(ABC^C) = P(A^CB^C) = P(A|B)P(ABC)/2$$
$$P(AB^CC) = P(A^CB^CC) = P(A|C)P(ABC)/2$$

Comment: Thank you for a very informative answer. Is there any approximation that can be made if we say that $P(A)$ is very small, say on the order of $10^{-10}$ or less, and that $P(A|B)$ and $P(A|C)$ are much larger, say in the range from $0.1$ to $0.8$?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to evaluate $\mathsf P(A\mid B,C)$ knowing only $\mathsf P(A\mid B), \mathsf P(A\mid C)$.   You need to know how $B,C$ relate to each other, and how they do so when conditioned on $A$ too.

---

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B,C) ~&=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,B,C)}{\mathsf P(B,C)} \\[1ex] &=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(B,C\mid A)~\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B,C)} \\[1ex] &=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A,C)~\mathsf P(A\mid C)}{\mathsf P(B\mid C)} \\[1ex] &=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(C\mid A,B)~\mathsf P(A\mid B)}{\mathsf P(C\mid B)}\end{align}$$

---

If you also know that $B,C$ *are independent*, that allows that:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B,C) ~&=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,B,C)}{\mathsf P(B,C)} \\[1ex] &=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(B,C\mid A)~\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(C)} \\[1ex] &=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A,C)~\mathsf P(A\mid C)}{\mathsf P(B)} \\[1ex] &=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(C\mid A,B)~\mathsf P(A\mid B)}{\mathsf P(C)}\end{align}$$